# How to avoid play two videos in html

Tags: javascript, html

In my website i want to avoid play two videos simultaneously.

I think if i put a id in the video when user click to this video i take this id and put it in a variable and if user click to another video i put the first video in pause automatically.

```
<video id="video_1" onclick="manage_video();"
       preload="none" poster="images/" controls 
       data-video_id="video_1">
    <source src="videos/<?php echo $data['post_video_adress']?>"/>
</video>
```

In manage videos i put a simple alert() to see if the click work

```
function manage_video(){
   alert("ok");
}
```

But when i click on the video this does not work

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all of your video's and listen for the `play` event with each video. This event is fired whenever a video starts playing. So when listening to that event we know when a video starts playing. And from here we can select all other video's and pause them whenever this event happens.

This example below selects all the video elements, loops over each video element and starts listening for the `play` event. Whenever a video starts playing the `pauseOtherVideos` function is called. That function loops over all video's we found earlier and pauses all the video's except for the one that started playing.

```
// Get all <video> elements.
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

// Pause all <video> elements except for the one that started playing.
function pauseOtherVideos({ target }) {
  for (const video of videos) {
    if (video !== target) {
      video.pause();
    }
  }
}

// Listen for the 'play' event on all the <video> elements.
for (const video of videos) {
  video.addEventListener('play', pauseOtherVideos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you work very nice.I did not know the event play

Comment: When i want to read a specific part of my video it'is not possible the cursor go to the actual part everyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: What does *read a specific part of my video* mean? If you have a new question then please submit it as a new question so everyone can see it and help you.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out. Others with the same question can then see the answer.